# Как правильно создать таблицу для размещения объявлений в Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Цель создать базу для размешений вакансий и резюме.

как правильно создать таблицу?
В одной таблице сделать все необходимые поля
или же создать отдельные таблицы для резюме и для вакансии?

На главной странице сайта нужно вывести случайный список резюме и вакансий в месте.
в этом случае если сделаю 2 таблицы как правильно вывести?

Comment: Можно и так и так в принципе сделать. Оба варианта имеют свои плюсы и минусы. Если почти все поля одинаковые у них - делайте одну таблицу. Если будет много различающихся полей - делайте лучше две разные.

Comment: По второму вопросу - обычно их выводят же не вперемешку, а в отдельных фреймах, так что там два разных запроса к разным таблицам будет норм. Но при желании можно и в одном запросе к базе вывести данные из двух таблиц, проблем особых нет.

Comment: Две таблицы - как минимум несерьёзно. С учётом того, что именно составляет массив данных в указанной предметной области, таблиц должно быть гораздо больше - одних таблиц-справочников будет минимум десяток.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Теперь я понял как поступить. сделаю в разных таблицах и вывод в разных фреймах.